# WCF WebMethod returns XML that is not complete

Tags: xml, wcf, webmethod, memorystream

I just noticed that XML show in my browser window is incomplete. I am not sure if this is a limitation of how much information can sent across the wire via WebMethod call or if I am not accounting for something. I know the XML is complete when I get it from the database to the service, however, when it displayed via the WebMethod in a browser, the information (XML) is incomplete/ cut off for some reason.

Does anyone know what could be happening and/or how I can remedy this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Probably there may be some invalid character in xml because of which browser is not able to display it completely. You may be able to see complete xml in developer tools of browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not the case. It is stopping write in the middle of an xml tag that has already been repeated several time already. It is almost like there is a limit on the amount of data sent or received from the service.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root of my issue. I was getting an ObjectResult back and doing FirstOrDefault to get the resulting value. The issue here is that I should have been looping through the ResultSet to get the whole value value, instead of utilizing part of returned value provided by the FirstOrDefault.